# Is it possible to be more pythonic?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I create five threads to do something.

```
threadList = [threading.Thread(target=want) for i in range(5)] # create five threads and save it in a list.
for i in threadList: # use for loop to start them.
    i.start()
```

Is it possible to start those thread and save them in a `list` at the same time?

I want only one line code.

Comment: Writing everything in one line of code is *not* Pythonic. Avoiding `for` loops for the sake of it is not Pythonic.

Comment: @kaya3 Right.But I think I create it and save it in a `list`.But if I want to start them,I have to use for loop to start them.Why didn't do this at the same time?

Comment: The code you already have is fine. The only concrete thing you have asked for is how to fit it all in one line, which is like asking how to make your code worse.

Comment: @kaya3 Thanks,I get it.Maybe it couldn't.

Comment: You could, but it would be worse. Like `threadList = [t.start() or t for t in [threading.Thread(target=want)] for i in range(5)]` or `threadList = [(lambda t: (t.start(), t)[1])(threading.Thread(target=want)) for i in range(5)]`. List comprehensions are not more Pythonic than `for` loops; using the right tool for the job is what matters.

Comment: @kaya3 Hahhhh,Yes,it looked a little complex.Maybe sometime it is not good to seek one-line code.

Comment: Seeking to write your code in one line is *never* good - unless you're playing code golf or some other challenge. You should seek to write it in a simple way, and it doesn't matter whether the simple way uses one line or more.

Comment: @kaya3 Just another one: `[(t := threading.Thread(target=want)).start() or t for i in range(5)]`

Comment: @HeapOverflow Maybe it can only be used in python 3.8,right?

Comment: @kevin777 Yes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would say that simply using a for-loop rather than a list generator would be considered more pythonic as it increases readability.

Secondly, you could try using thread pools rather than adding threads to a generic list.

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

threads = 5
pool = ThreadPool(threads)
results = pool.map(want)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to clarify that the Pool is instanciated with the number of threads/workers. I edited my response for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Condensing this is not more Pythonic.  It just becomes more confusing to read, and if you write hundreds of lines like this, i can end up being a huge hassle trying to figure out what is going on.

You might want to check out [pep-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length), as that explains how to style your code. It's more pythonic to write the code as you did in the example you gave.